# Estimate of lower bound of $|s(s+1)|$ in contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, upper-lower-bounds

I want to do following contour integration

$$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+\infty} \frac {a^s}{s(s+1)} ds$$

Here c>0 ,a>1 and $\text{Re(s)=c}$
While doing a contour integration, I needed to estimate the lower bound of the function $\ |s(s+1)|$ where$\ s$ is complex number. The contour is shown in figure(below). Here$\ s$ is the complex number on the Semicircle $\text{C(T)}$ of given contour in figure,with the radius of semicircle being $\text{T}$. According to the book I have to prove:
$$|s(s+1)| \geq T^2/2$$

I have been trying it for last 30 minutes but unable to prove it.[image]

Edit: In the figure O is origin and C>0 is some point on real number line

Comment: It is too much large

Comment: Note that the book says "for all large $T$". The inequality does not hold for, say, $T = c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\inf_{\Re(s) \le 0,|s|=T}|s(s+1)| = \inf_{\Re(s) \le 0,|s|=T}T |s+1|= T|T-1|$$
For $T$ very small and $T$ very large $T|T-1| \ge T^2/2$.

$T^2 - T=T^2/2$ means $T = 0$ or $T = 2$ thus $T|T-1| \ge T^2/2$ fails for $T \in [1,2)$ and it succeeds for $T \ge 2$.

And $T - T^2 = T^2/2$ means $T =0$ or $T = 2/3$ thus $T|T-1| \ge T^2/2$ fails for $T \in (2/3,1]$ and it succeeds for $T \in [0,2/3]$.

Comment: Sir, I have added more details into question. Here $|s|$ should be equal to distance from origin and therefore should be less then T?

Comment: If you are not capable to define your function I can't help. If you mean $|s(s+c)|$ then it works the same way as I did whenever $c > 0$

Comment: Added original question

Comment: Are you capable to define your circle ? Also I'm quite sure you don't understand what kind of contour and circle we need for $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+\infty} \frac {a^s}{s(s+1)} ds$

Comment: The contour allows to use the Residue theorem. If one proves the integral over the arc vanishes as the radius goes to infinity, one has: $$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{a^s}{s(s+1)} ds=2\pi i \sum_{\text{Re}(s)<c} \text{Res}_c\left(\frac{a^s}{s(s+1)}\right)$$

Comment: @reuns Thanks for help. I got the answer